# Copy LVM Volume Group to a new single hard disk

Tags: ubuntu, lvm, ext4, dd

I have a headless Ubuntu (18.04) server with 3 hard drives each partitioned to a single lvm volume group for a combined size of 6Tb. I recently purchased a new hard drive that is 8Tb and I want to get everything copied onto the new hard drive. I've partitioned the new 8Tb drive and set up an ext4 file system on it (I don't want to use logical volumes if I don't have to).

I've found many posts about copying from one logical volume to another, but I can't find anything about going from a logical volume to a purely physical volume so I'm wondering if this is something that anyone has done before or would know how to do?

Would it be possible to use something like `dd if=/dev/lvm/root of=/dev/sdd1` or will that not work? Will I perhaps have to go through and manually copy the parts of the LVM filesystem onto my newly partitioned HDD?

Comment: `cp -a src dest`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> but I can't find anything about going from a logical volume to a purely physical volume so I'm wondering if this is something that anyone has done before or would know how to do?

That's because that is not possible to do. What you should do is backup your data, with copy commands. Use the combination of `tar` and *pipe* to do that. You would keep the same rights.

Here are a few options:

```
cp -a /lvm_partition_a /physical_partition_a

cd /lvm_partition_a; tar cf - . | (cd /physical_partition_a; tar xf -)
```

Comment: Thanks, I was afraid this was going to be what I would have to do, which is why I kicked off a `cp -a` yesterday right after posting this question ;) I was just hoping there would be some single command that wouldn't require me to manually copy everything around, drive by drive or folder by folder.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by @jordanm, the simplest option is to `cp -a src dst` or `rsync --progress -av /src/ /dst` your source filesystems to the new disk filesystem.

But in case you reconsider your willing to get rid of lvm, you can do the migration online, without copying any file, using the `pvmove /dev/sdb /dev/sdd` command (first `pvcreate /dev/sdd` on the new disk, and then for each physical volume corresponding to old disks, run a `pvmove`)

Comment: Thanks. I don't know why I didn't think of `rsync`. I use it all the time at work (I prefer it over `scp`).Unfortunately I will not be reconsidering lvm at this time. I currently have a single root (/) partition using lvm and will instead be using the 3 hard drives (and the new 4th one) for a split filesystem setup. I ran into issues with lvm when I was wanting to shrink the lvm partition since I didn't have any storage media large enough to back everything up. I'll now be using one drive for /home, another for a Nextcloud instance, one for Plex, and then everything else on the last one.

Answer (score 0):

I want to copy 2 LVM drives to one bigger drive. The LVM is 4TB with 2 2TB drives and I got one 4TB single drive I want to copy it to. What command would do that?

A lvs command shows it like this:

root      sg30-vg   -wi-a-----  <3.64t
swap_1    sg30-vg   -wi-a----- 976.00m

fdisk -l shows them like this with the /dev/sdd I want to copy it to.

Disk /dev/mapper/sg30--vg-root: 3.64 TiB, 3999256281088 bytes, 7811047424 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes

Disk /dev/mapper/sg30--vg-swap_1: 976 MiB, 1023410176 bytes, 1998848 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 33553920 bytes

Disk /dev/sdd: 3.64 TiB, 4000787030016 bytes, 7814037168 sectors
Disk model: USB 3.0 TOSATA
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes

So would it be a command like this:

pvmove /dev/sdb /dev/sdc /dev/sdd

But I don't want to remove it from the 2 drives it's on now.

Is there like a pvcopy not sure.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I copy it like this:

pvcreate /dev/sdd # initialise the new drive for LVM
vgextend sg30-vg  /dev/sdd # add the new drive to the old and existing vg
pvmove /dev/sdb5 /dev/sdd # copy the old vg from the first old drive to the new drive
pvmove /dev/sdc /dev/sdd  # then copy the rest of the old vg from the second old drive to the new drive
vgreduce sg30-vg /dev/sdb # now remove the old vg from the first old drive
vgreduce sg30-vg /dev/sdc # and remove the old vg from the second old drive
pvremove /dev/sdb #  decommission the first old drive from LVM
pvremove /dev/sdc #  and finally decommission the second old drive from LVM

It worked but now it can't boot. The other one I copy looks like this:

fdisk -l /dev/sdc
Disk /dev/sdc: 1.82 TiB, 2000398934016 bytes, 3907029168 sectors
Disk model: USB 3.0 TOSATA
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 33553920 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0xdce13ae7

Device     Boot   Start        End    Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sdc1  *       2048     999423     997376  487M 83 Linux
/dev/sdc2       1001470 3907028991 3906027522  1.8T  5 Extended
/dev/sdc5       1001472 3907028991 3906027520  1.8T 8e Linux LVM
fdisk -l /dev/sdd
Disk /dev/sdd: 3.64 TiB, 4000787030016 bytes, 7814037168 sectors
Disk model: USB 3.0 TOSATA
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes

So how can I fix this it don't have this boot.

/dev/sdc1  *       2048     999423     997376  487M 83 Linux

Thank you.